# Find method criteria not working for MongoDB view

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB collection with document structure as below:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5b58673721b4b95a193d4e91"),
"pageId" : "page1",
"fields" : [ 
    {
        "fieldId" : "Field1",
        "value" : "test"
    }, 
    {
        "fieldId" : "Field2",
        "value" : 6.0
    },
    {
        "fieldId" : "Field3",
        "value" : 8.0
    }
]}
```

For reporting purposes I wanted data to be in below format:

```
{ 
    "Field1" : "test", 
    "Field2" : 6.0, 
    "Field3" : 8.0, 
}
```

For that, I have created a view in MongoDB using the below aggregation query:

```
db.getCollection("collectionName").aggregate(
    [
        { 
            "$project" : {
                "fieldss" : {
                    "$arrayToObject" : {
                        "$map" : {
                            "input" : "$fields", 
                            "as" : "el", 
                            "in" : {
                                "k" : "$$el.fieldId", 
                                "v" : {
                                    "$ifNull" : [
                                        "$$el.value", 
                                        ""
                                    ]
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 
        { 
            "$replaceRoot" : {
                "newRoot" : "$fieldss"
            }
        }
    ], 
    { 
        "allowDiskUse" : false
    }
)
```

This view gives me ouput as expected.
As per [mongodb documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/), I can use aggregate(), find() methods on views.
When I execute these methods without any criteria, it gives me all the documents in the expected format.
But when I pass provide criteria like {"Field1": "test"} to find() method,
It doesn't return any records. same happens when I put it in aggregate() $match.
Basically, the criteria match is not working in case of view.

Am I doing anything wrong?

I am using MongoDB version 4.0

Comment: What should be the output for above sample document when pass `{"Field1": "test"}` ?

Comment: Do you create the view from the aggregation in the question?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet it should return all the documents where key "Field1" has value as "test"

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, I created view from the aggregation I have mentioned.

Comment: You can use `$match` at the end of the pipeline. Something like this https://mongoplayground.net/p/zJ8caZHMReD

Comment: Just tested on 4.0.6, works as expected. Show how you create the view and how  you query it. It must be a typo somewhere.

Comment: @AlexBlex I'll check and let you know.

Comment: @AlexBlex yes, it is working fine. It was a naive mistake from my side. In some of the documents, fieldId contained dot(.) character. e.g. ("fieldId":"pageName.fieldId"). As MongoDB does not support keys with dot characters. Hence it was not working in some of the cases. Closing this question now.